# Embracing/or not ++i in one part of a code. K&R longest line example

Tags: c

```
int getline(char s[], int lim) 
{
    int c, i;

    for(i=0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if(c=='\n'){
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';

return i;
}
```

This example is from K&R book on C, chapter 1.9 on arrays. What I do not understand is why do we have to embrace `++i` inside `if` statement? Writing it outside should do the same work.

```
    if(c=='\n')
        s[i] = c;
    ++i;
    s[i] = '\0'
return 0;
}
```

In case of embracing `i` program works as intended, but on the second case(which in my opinion should do the same work and this is why I edited that part) it doesn't. I ran it through debugger and watched `i` which in both cases was correctly calculated and returned. But program still won't work without embracing `++i`. I don't get my print from `printf` statement, and Ctrl+D just won't work in terminal or XTerm(thorough CodeBlocks) I can't figure out why. Any hint please? Am I missing some logical step? Here is a complete code:

```
//Program that reads lines and prints the longest
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

int getline(char currentline[], int maxlinelenght);
void copy(char saveto[], char copyfrom[]);
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

int main(void)
{
    int len, max;
    char line[MAXLINE], longest[MAXLINE];

    max = 0;
    while( (len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0 )
        if(len > max){
            max = len;
            copy(longest, line);
        }
    if(max > 0)
        printf("StrLength:%d\nString:%s", max, longest);

return 0;
}
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

int getline(char s[], int lim) 
{
    int c, i;

    for(i=0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if(c=='\n'){
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';

return i;
}
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while( (to[i]=from[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
}
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

Comment: "Writing it outside should do the same work" -- I can't imagine why you think so, since it's so obviously false; code executed conditionally isn't executed if the condition isn't true.

Answer (score 2):

The line
`if(c == '\n')`
is equivalent to
`if(c != EOF)`

Does that help explain why the embracing occurs?

Answer (score 1):

The `++i` is inside the `if` statement because we do not want to increment `i` if we are not placing the `\n` character in the current index; that would result in leaving an index in between the last character of the input and the `\0` at the end of the character string.

Comment: By "the last character of the line", I think you mean "the last character of the file" or "the last character of the input".

Comment: You changed it to "the last character of the line or file", but I still think it should be just "the last character of the file". If it's the last character of a line and *not* the last character of the input, then there will be a `\n` there. This issue only arises at the end of the file. (And I think that's the fact that the OP is missing, so it's an important point.)

Comment: double check his provided function; using `getline`, there wouldn't be `\n` on the end of `s` at that point because it stops once c == EOF or C == `\n` and doesn't copy that character.  So at the end of a line is relevant too.

Comment: It *does* copy that character -- in the very `if` statement that we're discussing. That's the whole point.

Comment: but it hasn't copied it into `s` yet at that point and we only want to increment `i` if we end up copying the `\n` into `s` in the `if` statement.  `i` should not be incremented if the `\n` is not added to `s` in the `if` statement.

Comment: You're missing @ruakh's point. If c is `\n`, `++i` occurs whether it is inside the if or not, so there will only be a gap if the last line of the file is missing a `\n`.

Comment: OK, I see what his point is.  I misinterpreted @ruakh because in both scenarios, the function is retrieving "a line"; even if the end of that line is also the end of the file, it is still the end of the retrieved line.  However, I have adjusted my answer to be precisely correct.

Answer (score 1):

There is a logic there:

```
if(c=='\n'){
    s[i] = c;
    ++i;
}
```

It means only if you read an additional newline, you need to increment `i` one more in order to keep space for the `\0` character. If you put `++i` outside the `if` block. it means that it will always increase `i`  by `1` even there is no `newline input`, in this case, since `i` is already incremented in the `for loop` , there is already space for `\0`, therefore, `++i` again will be wrong. You can print the value of `i` and see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

The index specified by `i` is the location where the terminating null should be placed when there is no more input for the line. The location just before the index `i` contains the last valid character in the string.

Keep in mind that the loop that reads data from `stdin` can terminate for reasons other than reading a `\n` character.

If you had this construct:

```
if(c=='\n')
    s[i] = c;
++i;
```

then if the last character read from `stdin` wasn't a newline you would increment the index by one without writing anything into the location specified by the pre-incremented value of `i`. You would be effectively adding an unspecified character to the result.

Worse(?), if the `for` loop terminated because of the `i<lim-1` condition you would end up writing the terminating null character after the specified end of the array, resulting in undefined behavior (memory corruption).

Answer (score 0):

For loop can exit due to 3 conditions 
1. reading char limit reached or EOF encountered
2. New Line encountered

For first Case We need to store Null into string s , as i points to next position to last valid character read so no need to increment i.
But for second case , as i points to next position to last valid character read , we now store newline at that position then increment i for storing  NULL character.

Thats why we need to increment i in 2nd case not in 1st case.

```
 if(c=='\n'){
            s[i] = c;
            ++i;
        }
```

Comment: That's extremely hard to comprehend (although it is correct).

Comment: The bad English and typos are still there, e.g., "in this case we nhats why need not to increment i that's why ++i should come in"